# Is there a difference between the durability of the chains with 1/8 and 3/32 inch?

Tags: chain, drivetrain, single-speed

I mean, I have a single-speed bike and have chains width 1/8 inch.
The other standard I could use on my bike is 3/32 inch wide.

Is there a difference in durability?

Comment: Which chain you use is also determined by the rear sprocket and which single-speed freewheel.

Comment: Yes I am sure. I could change the complete drive-chain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. All other things being equal a 1/8" chain will be a tiny bit sturdier than a 3/32", just by virtue of the fact that the plates are a little thicker.

I also have a single speed bike, I also choose to run a 1/8" chain.

Answer (score 2):

In addition, 1/8" chain doesn't flex sideways like 3/32" chain does, so while its unsuitable for derailleurs, its great for tandem timing chains, and for single-speeds.    The lack of flex also contributes to its durability.